# Cannot create index on heroku shared database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to create a custom index on the shared postgresql database on Heroku in a rails migration:

```
-- execute("create index on items using gin(to_tsvector('english', name));")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 1: create index on items using gin(to_tsvector('english', name)...
                     ^
: create index on items using gin(to_tsvector('english', name));
```

It works fine in development, postgresql is installed through Homebrew (9.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the postgres manual:

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] name ON table [ USING method ]
    ( { column | ( expression ) } [ opclass ] [, ...] )
    [ WITH ( storage_parameter = value [, ... ] ) ]
    [ TABLESPACE tablespace ]
    [ WHERE predicate ]
```

I think you are missing the NAME of the index.

Comment: at some point around version 9, the index name was made optional (well, postgresql will automatically name indices if you don't specify it) but the Heroku shared db is version 8 iirc.